# Populating Multiple DropDownLists from XML (LINQ)

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

Simple LINQ query that is eluding me.  I've done lots of googleing, to no avail.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Clients>
  <Client name="TestClient">
    <cat ID="1" value="Computers"/>
    <cat ID="2" value="Ayyy"/>
    <cat ID="3" value="lmao"/>
  </Client>

  <Client name="DoTheNeedful">
    <cat ID="1">ارومیه </cat>
    <cat ID="2">اشنویه </cat>
    <cat ID="3">بوکان </cat>
  </Client>
</Clients>
```

In my viewmodel, there's a variable declared as:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Category { get; set; }
```

My LINQ query:

```
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Controllers/ClientConfig.xml");
        string whichDD = "TestClient";

        var model = new TicketViewModel
        {

            Category =
            from dropDown in XDocument.Load(path).Descendants("Client")
            where dropDown.Attribute("name").Value == whichDD
            from name in dropDown.Descendants("name")                                
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = name.Attribute("ID").Value,
                Text = name.Attribute("value").Value
            }
        };
```

My view:

```
@model IEGTicketingSite.Models.TicketViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ticket";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryID,
new SelectList(Model.Category, "Value", "Text"))
```

I'm trying to get to where I can reference "TestClient" and get a dropdownlist with

```
Computers
Ayyy
lmao
```

Comment: do a google search on `C# binding dropdown to xml file` tons of examples online

Comment: I have done a google search for this very thing.  The examples given are formatting their XML file in such a way that doesn't work well for multiple lists.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dropDown.Descendants("cat")` instead of `dropDown.Descendants("name")`?  There are no nodes called "name" under the "Client" node, only nodes called "cat".

Comment: so for example something like this wouldn't work..? 
`DataSet ddlDataSource = new DataSet(); ddlDataSource.ReadXml(MapPath("~/Controllers/ClientConfig.xml"));
DropDownList1.DataSource = ddlDataSource;
DropDownList1.DataBind();`

Comment: @juharr I tried this, but the dropdownlist remains blank.

Comment: @MethodMan I am using MVC format, so I want to get the data back as my Category IEnumerable object and use that model in other places.

Comment: @juharr Disregard my earlier comment, this fixed me up.  I wish I could hug you.  Thanks!

Comment: @SonnyChilds good to hear, You should also note that your query will fail if you switch `whichDD` to "DoTheNeedful" because that "Client" node has "cat" nodes that do not have "value" attributes.

Comment: @juharr Thanks. I actually edited the XML doc right before I posted it here; I'll be taking care of that issue.  Can't go sharing actual client names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

juharr solved this question.

Changed:

```
dropDown.Descendants("name")
```

to:

```
dropDown.Descendants("cat")
```